# sending email attachment with sendmail command

Tags: sendmail

```
email() {
  sendmail -t <<EOF
To: xyz@gmail.com
Cc: xyz@gmail.com
Subject: This is test email
Content-Type: text/html
Attachment: file1.html
<html><font size="3">Hi Team,<br>
<br>
$(cat file2.html)
<br>
<br>
This is an autogenerated email.<br>
<br>
Regards,
<br>
Dev Team.<br>
</font></html>
EOF
}
```

we need to display the contents of file2.html as HTML format and file1.html will be send as an attachment.
If we will use sendmail -at, then it throws an error saying -a illegal option. I have gone through few blogs but all are using mailx command , as in my
requirement we need the email body contents should display in HTML format , I cannot use mailx command.

Comment: add a new line after `Attachment:` , note you will have only one file, which maybe displayed inline or not depending on your mail client.

Comment: The sendmail command does not generate content; it operates at a lower level, The `Attachment` header has no meaning to sendmail, and does not cause it to include the (possibly MIME-encoded) content of `file1.html` in the message. You will have to use some other program to produce the body and attachment-related headers of you message.